# Change fragment background on create view dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to change fragment background on load dynamically, Below code do that for me, But I have an issue on run-time and that is background changes happen after showing the fragment with default background.

for example when I want to swipe to load another fragment, On transition fragment appears with default background setting and after loading fragment and waiting a little moment that codes work at **first time** load.

I want to know where I'm wrong

```
  @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible){
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
        View view=RegisterFragment.this.getView();
        if (view!=null)
        {
            RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
            layout.setBackgroundResource(Application.color);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.back_layout).setBackgroundResource(Application.color);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override below method which will help you to update UI run-time while loading fragment:

```
@Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {

       layout.setBackgroundResource(Application.color);

}
```